# I upgraded 14.04 to 16.04 last night and now I can't view any videos on Facebook..

Tags: vlc, facebook

What do I need to do (use) to view the videos.  I tried to install VLC but that's not working either.  I don't know how to insert code, so is there a clickable site for doing this?

Thanks

Comment: During upgrade did you check box on the offer to install 3rd party non-free software ? This gives you multimedia codec etc you need ... Also available subsequently